# how to create range datetime for data without switch in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i get onlinedata,i want show in cells base Specified time,datetime range is 9:00:00 to 13:00:00 and i want each 5 minute get data from onlinedata.i dont use switch or if-else

```
    List<TradeDto> cMIMData = new List<TradeDto>();
    cMIMData = (List<TradeDto>)data;
```

cMIMData have TradeDate,TradeDateTime,TradeTime,...,and value properties

Comment: it is really unclear what you're trying to do or where you're stuck. I see some code, which is great; but: how does that code relate to the question? are you saying you want to group the list into 5 minute chunks based on one of those 3 properties at the bottom? or...? also: "i dont use switch or if-else"  - well... why not? *ever*?

Comment: i am so sorry for my poor description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your description was not good enough, must use while base on date by increase 5 min, you can use loop(while,for,...) and check online data with lambda expression

```
cMIMData = cMIMData.OrderByDescending(x => x.TradeDateTime).ToList();
startDate = new DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, currentDate.Day, 9, 5, 0);
endDate = new DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, currentDate.Day, 13, 0, 0);

                while (startDate < endDate)
                {
                    var value = cMIMData.Where(x => x.TradeDateTime.Date == your date &&  x.TradeTime >= startDate.AddMinutes(-5).TimeOfDay &&
                    x.TradeTime <= startDate.TimeOfDay).First();  //get last item value in Limit specified time               
                startDate = startDate.AddMinutes(5);
                }
```